# Failed to load module script - ViteJS Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, deployment, module, vite

I finished a small personal project and deployed it via github.
The problem is that I have a mime type error (see screen) in the console once the project is deployed (on github). In dev I have no worries.
Therefore, on the deployed site I only have the html and css loaded.
I specify that for this project I used ViteJS.

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="./src/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tilt+Neon&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script type="module" src="./src/main.ts" defer></script>
        <title>Pogflix - Movies</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Pogflix</h1>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div id="search-container">
                <div id="search">
                    <input placeholder="Find your movie..." type="text" id="search-movie" />
                    <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
                </div>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I would like my script to be loaded to take advantage of the app's features.

Does anyone have any idea of the problem?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to use a typescript file as js. Browser cant speak typescript.
The reason it works seamlessly with vite is that vite transpiles all your code to JavaScript and only then serves it.

It looks like you just uploaded your project to github as is. If that's the case you need to run a build script like `vite build` or `tsc` / `npm run build` (depending an how your project is setup) and then only upload the generated static files to your github page.

Here you find more info about [vite build](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html)

Comment: Oh thank for your explanation! i will see that  :)